# Is it possible to read constants from file in C?

Tags: c, file

I have a file called definitions.h like this:

```
#define PACKAGE 270
#define IMPORT 271
#define COMILLAS 272
#define FUNCION 273
...
```

And I have a text file with the next information:

```
PACKAGE package
IMPORT import
COMILLAS "
FUNCION func
```

Is it possible to read the second file in a way that allows me to load in two arrays the constant itself and the lowercase words? In one array it would be PACKAGE, IMPORT with its defined value associated and in the second the lowercase words (package, import, ", func)

I tried reading the uppercase words as strings but I don't know how to change them to a constant.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you elaborate? Do you want to read from the 2 files to create arrays with their contents? That would only involve reading from the file and assigning the elements to the array.

Comment: You want this to happen on compile time or?

Comment: What I need is to read only the second file. The thing is that I want the uppercase words (PACKAGE, IMPORT..) be the constants defined in the first file, not strings. For example, I want to store PACKAGE (the defined value associated with 270) and not "PACKAGE" (the string that is in the file). @J...S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, your program must contain a string value for each name you want to translate.  Not just macros, which get converted to their values early in compilation, leaving no trace of the name you used there.

So you would need a file, say definitions.c, containing something like:

```
struct TokenNameEntry {
    int value;
    const char* name;
};

const struct TokenNameEntry tokens[] = {
    { PACKAGE, "PACKAGE" },
    { IMPORT, "IMPORT" },
    { COMILLAS, "COMILLAS" },
    { FUNCION, "FUNCION" },
    // ...
};
```

But what about Don't Repeat Yourself? Now if you add or remove any constants, you need to update both definitions.h and definitions.c.

To make this better, I like to use a "macros file".  This contains just repeated uses of one or more macros, so that other files can define the macros and make that file say various things about the data it contains.  Let's call this file definitions_macros.h:

```
/* definitions_macros.h
 * NO INCLUDE GUARD: A file may redefine the macros and include
 * more than once. */
DEFINE_TOKEN(PACKAGE, 270)
DEFINE_TOKEN(IMPORT, 271)
DEFINE_TOKEN(COMILLAS, 272)
DEFINE_TOKEN(FUNCION, 273)
// ...
```

Then definitions.h would change to look something like:

```
#ifndef CONST_DEFINITIONS_H_
#define CONST_DEFINITIONS_H_

#define DEFINE_TOKEN(symbol, value) symbol = value,
typedef enum {
#include "definitions_macros.h"
} TokenType;
#undef DEFINE_TOKEN

const char* token_to_name(TokenType tok);
TokenType token_from_name(const char* name);

#endif
```

And definitions.c becomes:

```
#include "definitions.h"

struct TokenNameEntry {
    TokenType value;
    const char* name;
};

#define STRINGIFY_NOEXPAND(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_NOEXPAND(x)
#define DEFINE_TOKEN(symbol, value) { symbol, STRINGIFY(symbol) },
const struct TokenNameEntry tokens[] = {
#include "definitions_macros.h"
};
#undef DEFINE_TOKEN
const unsigned int num_tokens = sizeof(tokens)/sizeof(tokens[0]);

const char* token_to_name(TokenType tok) {
    // TODO!
}

TokenType token_from_name(const char* name) {
    // TODO!
}
```

And now you have a way to get from a string you read from a line in the file to the numeric value you want to store to represent it. You can easily change the list or values of these constant tokens in just one place. If anything else needs to do something strongly patterned with all those values (maybe a switch statement?), you can reuse the same macros file. If you want to associate more data with these constants, you can add more arguments to the `DEFINE_TOKEN` macro.